# QgsComposerTextTableV2 minimal implementation?

Tags: qgis, python

I would like to use the richer data and styling API QgsComposerTextTableV2 offers. However I get this error when adding it to the composer:

TypeError: QGraphicsScene.addItem(QGraphicsItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsComposerTextTableV2'

here is the code:

```
    r = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
    c = QgsComposition(r)
    rows = self.buildRows() # A list of lists
    composerTable = QgsComposerTextTableV2(c, False)
    composerTable.setContents(rows)
    c.addItem(composerTable)
    return c
```

could someone provide code demonstrating a minimal implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer tables are a special type of item... a "multi frame" item. They require QgsComposerFrame items to actually display their content. It's done this way as a single table can have its contents shown over multiple frames (eg on different pages). Here's some code which should work:

```
# grab first composition for now
c=iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()

# create a text table
table = QgsComposerTextTableV2( c, False )

# add it to the composition
c.addMultiFrame(table)

# create 2 frame items to display contents of table in
frame1 = QgsComposerFrame( c, table, 5, 5, 100, 30 )
frame1.setFrameEnabled( True )
frame2 = QgsComposerFrame( c, table, 5, 40, 100, 30 )
frame2.setFrameEnabled( True )

# add the frames to the composition. These are the items which actually
# show the contents of the table
table.addFrame( frame1 )
c.addItem( frame1 )
table.addFrame( frame2 )
c.addItem( frame2 )

# setup the table's columns.
# *Important* QGIS will crash if col1 and col2 go out of scope. You may need
# to make them global
col1 = QgsComposerTableColumn('col 1')
col2 = QgsComposerTableColumn('another col' )
table.setColumns([col1,col2])

# set some sample content text
table.setContents([['row 1','text'],['row2','more text']])
```